# Applications gone from Dock. How to restore?

Tags: macos, dock

Somehow the Applications icon is gone from my Dock. However I can't just drag the Applications folder (from Finder) into the Dock. How else can I restore it?

Is there a config file somewhere for the Dock that I can just edit with vi and fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just drag it back ?

Comment: Are you on Lion or Snow Leopard?

Comment: Snow Leopard. One has to drag it to the bottom, then select "show as folder".

Comment: Is your problem fixed?  If so, please accept an answer by clicking the green check mark next to the voting icons.

Answer (score 24):

Hmm, depending on how precisely you formulated the question there are several possible answers:

1. The Applications folder is missing from the Dock

   - Navigate to Computer in Finder (Shift-Command-C)
   - Open local hard drive (usually called "Macintosh HD" or computername)
   - Drag the Applications folder to the Dock *(near the end where the other folders and the trash are located)*
   - Right-click the folder in the Dock and select show as folder
2. The Applications folder/link is missing from the Favorites list in any Finder window

   - Step 1 and 2 as above
   - Drag the Applications folder to the Favorites list
3. You are actually missing the Launchpad icon from the Dock

   - Step 1 and 2 as above
   - Open the Applications folder
   - Locate Launchpad and drag it to the Dock (near the beginning this time)

Comment: If you do #1, it adds the apps folder to the Dock but the icon is wrong... the icon is the address book's. I then went into its options and selected "show as folder" and that fixed the icon.

Comment: It defaults to Stack then which just shows a stack of icons of the folder content. Fixed above.

Comment: Alernative #3 helped me.

Comment: You saved my time. I was looking for this issue's solution a long time.

Answer (score 6):

go to finder. in the left panel, find the Applications folder. right click and select "Add to Dock", when the App folder shows in the dock - if it shows differently than before, again right click, and "Display as" select "Folder".

Answer (score 2):

You can find the **Applications** folder by clicking on the Finder icon in the Dock.

Then typing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. In the sheet window opened type `/Applications`. The Finder will the Go the folder. From there, just drag it back to your Dock.

If you're talking about the **App Store** icon:

[image: mac app store]

Invoke **Spotlight**, type `App Store` and then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd>.
A Finder window will open with the App Store app selected, and you'll just have to drag it back to the Dock.

Answer (score 2):

You have to drag it onto the "folders and files" section of the dock, which is next to the trash can.

You cannot put a folder in the main applications section of the dock.

When you drop it on the dock, it will not immediately allow you to add a new item - it will instead attempt to let you drop it onto something on the dock. You may need to hold it in between two icons for a second or so before the icons slide to the side, then you can drop it on the dock.

Alternatively, you can type this into a shell to reset the dock to the default state:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock
```

It will also reset a few other settings. See `defaults read com.apple.dock` to see what will be deleted.

This may also work for you:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-apps
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-others
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

though i use mac osx 10.7.4 and this is how i did it, i went to applications through  go which is at the top with the finder,the applications opened, i then dragged the small application folder which is at the top of the applications to my Dock, then i right clicked and choose the option folder.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue after trying a few of the above... i used finder, then mac HD when the applications folder appeared in the list below i dragged and dropped it on dock. then show as folder.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Open Finder > Application > Find Launchpad.app and drag to your Dock.

Comment: This answer is the same as several others here and doesn't contain any new info.  Additionally, the OP is not asking how to add Launchpad to their dock.  Please [edit] your answer to add new info not already provided.  See [answer] for info on how to properly answer a question.

Answer (score -2):

Drag Launchpad.app to the Dock.  I am using Maverick 10.9.2